# golang appengine internal server error

Tags: google-app-engine, go, internal-server-error

I am trying to develop custom User model/authentication code in Go on GAE. The following code is a simple modification of some code in the demos/guestbook application:

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("User").Filter("Email =", email)
users := make([]User, 0, 1)
if _, err := q.GetAll(c, &users); err != nil {
   http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
   return
}
```

Where email is pulled from a form. It just queries the datastore for a User with the given email. It works fine if the User with the email exists, and dies with an "Internal Server Error" page if they don't. What I don't understand (I guess about error handling in Go, or maybe datastore querying), is why I can't do anything else within that `if error` block. A slight mod like this:

```
if _, err := q.GetAll(c, &users); err != nil {
   fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\n", "user not found")
}
```

produces the same "Internal Server Error" page instead of just printing "user not found".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is tough to say without seeing the rest of your code, but the main point is that when you say:

```
if _, err := q.GetAll(c, &users); err != nil {
   fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\n", "user not found")
}
```

The inner statement will only be triggered if there was an error during the query, not if the query returns nothing. Therefore you aren't actually entering that block of code - my best guess (without seeing the code) is that your `Internal Server Error` is being triggered elsewhere, perhaps somewhere where you are treating `users` as a variable that contains data. If you want to print out that message if no user was matched, you could do something simple like check the length of the response - if it is `0`, no results were returned and you can print your message:

```
     if len(users) == 0 {
         fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\n", "user not found")
     }
```

There is likely a more idiomatic way, but I believe that will work for your situation (it will print just as you state there - you may want to handle it differently).